# How to remove CALayer mask margin? + how to position UILabel properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, masking

I am trying to create the effect of the text color inversing while being intercepted by the background layer.
As you can see in the screenshot below, i have a blue CAShapeLayer moving from left to right and a mask layer directly attached to it, moving accordingly. Strangely there is a gap between the two layers.

My Code for the layers:

```
//Add Shape Layer
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.contentView.frame)
initPostion = -contentView.frame.size.width+initialVisibility

colorStripeLayer.path = path.CGPath
colorStripeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.71, green:0.86, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0).CGColor
colorStripeLayer.frame = self.contentView.frame
colorStripeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(initPostion, 0, 0)
self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(colorStripeLayer, atIndex: 0)

//white UILabel Masking
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
maskLayer.frame = self.contentView.bounds
```

Additionaly I wanted to place the white text exactly underneath the black one, but even after setting all the attributes, it still positions quite randomly.

Code for the labels:

```
textLabel?.layer.mask = maskLayer
textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

let whiteLabel = UILabel(frame: textLabel!.frame)
whiteLabel.text = textLabel!.text
whiteLabel.font = textLabel!.font
whiteLabel.textAlignment = textLabel!.textAlignment
whiteLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
contentView.insertSubview(whiteLabel, belowSubview: textLabel!)
```

Animation is just a simple x-axis translation, done in pop.

Can anyone help here?

[2 Problems here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiImJ.png)

Comment: When do you add shape layer? (viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear)?

Comment: It is used in a UITableViewCell, so I initialize everything in awakeFromNib

Comment: in `awakeFromNib` method the frames are not yet correct and that's why you get wrong dimension of layer.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: try with `layoutSubviews` method, or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`...

Comment: Okay, layoutSubviews gives an interesting result. Now both Labels are equally offset. The Cell is a basic Cell with its TextLabel being setup in IB..